# GL_TEXTURE_2D aliasing problems issues, which are not present on GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to implement a depth peeling algorithm for rendering transparent objects. For depth peel buffer where I store depth values after each transparency path, I use `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`. Sampling from this texture doesn't produce any aliasing issues:

[image]

Unfortunately, this texture format is not supported on my target platform, and I have to use `GL_TEXTURE_2D` instead, but I have a lot of aliasing issues when I sample from `GL_TEXTURE_2D`
[image]

For me, it seems that either some undesired filtering is performed when I sample depth values from GL_TEXTURE_2D, or the texture coordinates are computed incorrectly, thus depth comparison with current fragment depth is performed incorrectly

Here is my fragment shader part where I sample GL_TEXTURE_2D:

```c
    ivec2 dbSize = textureSize(uOpaqueDepthMap, 0);
    float opaquePathDepth1 = texelFetch(uOpaqueDepthMap, ivec2(ceil(gl_FragCoord.xy)), 0).z;
    if(opaquePathDepth1 < gl_FragCoord.z)
        discard;
    else
    {
        ivec2 dpSize = textureSize(uDepthPeelMap, 0);
        float transparentPathDepth = texture(uDepthPeelMap, (gl_FragCoord.xy - vec2(0.5, 0.5)) / vec2(dpSize)).z;
        
        if(transparentPathDepth >= gl_FragCoord.z)
            discard;
    }
```

And here is code for GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE:

```c
    float opaquePathDepth1 = texture(uOpaqueDepthMap, gl_FragCoord.xy).z;
    if(opaquePathDepth1 < gl_FragCoord.z)
        discard;
    else
    {
        float transparentPathDepth = texture(uDepthPeelMap, gl_FragCoord.xy).z;
        
        if(transparentPathDepth >= gl_FragCoord.z)
            discard;
    }
```

Here are my `GL_TEXTURE_2D` configurations (captured by NVIDIA-NSIGHT):
[image]

Is there anything wrong in `GL_TEXTURE_2D` configuration, or in a way I compute texture coordinates?

Comment: 1) Could you remove all code that is irrelevant from your samples? For example, shadow mapping doesn't seem to play a role in all of this. Same for lighting. Just output a solid color for each box and then prepare a minimal example with just that. 2) Is there a reason why you access `uOpaqueDepthMap` with textureFetch while you access `uDepthPeelMap` with texture? There's also a difference with rounding (one time ceil and one time -0.5).

Comment: There is no particular reason. I tried both using `texelFetch`, and `texture` to check if there will be some positive effect, but the results are more/less similar. Also I tried different offsets for uDepthPeelMap (`+-vec2(0.5, 0.5)/no offset/ceil/floor).